# Difference in behaviour between tabular and flushleft environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, indentation

In response to my [earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/push-a-block-of-lines-to-the-right-margin/56843#comment119497_56843) the following working code has been provided:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
 some text\\
 some other text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My initial attempt was similar, but used the `flushleft` environment instead of `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{flushleft}
 some text\\
 some other text
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

The difference between the two approaches is that in the former one `\hfill` before the environment causes the text to stick to the right side of the page. In the latter one the text is still on the left side.

So, I wonder what fundamental difference between `tabular` and `flushleft` (I guess, between their implementations) causes this difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\flushleft` environment creates a paragraph with the lines that are aligned with the left-hand margin, which is exactly what you get:

[image]

TeX works in boxes, and the `\hfill` has no box to apply the fill to so that it gets pushed to the right.

If you place the `flushleft` environment within a `varwidth` then you would obtain the results you desire:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
 some text\\
 some other text
\end{flushleft}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```